# Which framework should be used to aggregate and joining the data of Kafka topics and store in to MySQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, bigdata, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-connect

I have data in two kafka topics from mysql using debezium-connector-mysql-plugin.
now i want to aggregate this data at daily level and store in to another mysql table.

please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: For aggregation and joining, you should most probably use KafkaStreams or KSQL. For storing into a Mysql results table, you could go with the JDBC sink connector.

Comment: Any another alternate if i do not use confluent platform. Thanks.

Comment: You can use apache storm for aggregation and storing in mysql

Comment: KafkaStreams is part of Apache Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

You've not really laid out your requirements, other than commenting that you don't want to use Confluent Platform (but not said why).

---

In general, with data in Kafka (regardless of where it comes from) you have different options for processing it:

- Bespoke consumer (probably a bad idea, given the availability of stream processing frameworks)
- KSQL ([use SQL to do your joins etc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html)) - part of Confluent Platform
- Kafka Streams - a Java library for doing stream processing. Part of Apache Kafka.
- Flink, Spark Streaming, Samza, Heron, etc etc etc

It's up to you which you use, and it's going to come down to factors such as

1. Existing technology in use (no point deploying a Spark cluster if you don't need to; conversely, if you already use Spark and have lots of developers trained on it then it could make sense to use it)
2. Language familiarity of developers - does it have to be a Java API, or is SQL more accessible
3. Capabilities of the framework/tool - do you need tight security integration, exactly-once processing, CEP, etc etc. Some of these will rule in or out the tool that you use.

---

Once you've joined and aggregated your data, a good pattern to follow is to write it back to Kafka (thus more loosely decoupling your design, and enabling separation of responsibilities of the components) and from there write it to MySQL using Kafka Connect and the JDBC Sink. Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka.

---

One final consideration : if you're taking data from MySQL, to process it and then write it back into MySQL… do you even need Kafka? Is there an appropriate reason to be using it and not just doing this processing in mySQL itself?

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Comment: Hi, we get ten million's+ records per day in our database. sometimes it go to fifteen million's records. we run a application where we aggregate this data and store into a table data repository where it used for analytics. we are also looking for a solution where we store such type of data in elastic-search for another application. i know Confluent platform, KSQL can easy our work. but right now, our organization looking for open source technologies. Thanks for your valuable inputs.